# override the behaviour of a standard object opportunitylineitemschedule in a vf page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, standard-objects

Can any one help me out with this requirement?
creating a custom object as custom schedule and overriding the behaviour of a standard object (opportunitylineitemschedule) in a vf page,by populating the custom fields .

Display the vf page in opportunitylineitem pagelayout.
any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Since a couple of days you are asking variations of the same question over and over again. Maybe it would help that you get your requirements straight first. Then it should be easier to ask questions which could actually be answered.